# Can roughtime be used as a timestamp authority?

Tags: trusted-timestamp

The [roughtime](https://blog.cloudflare.com/roughtime/) protocol gives a secure timestamp right now. Can it be used as a timestamp authority, to sign a document and later prove that it existed before a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to just use a cryptographic hash of your file as a nounce in your request to the roughtime servers.

Somebody apparently even [implemented a proof of concept](https://blog.merovius.de/2018/10/18/using-roughtime-as-a-cryptographic-notary.html), including a more sophisticated method.

Comment: URL of that blog post has changed; https://blog.merovius.de/posts/2018-10-10-using-roughtime-as-a-cryptographic-notary/ is now current.